"TypeError: Cyclical Structure in JSON Object during User Login in React Native/Expo"
I'm working on a React Native/Expo app where I implement user login. However, when attempting to log in a user, I encounter the following error:
Login error: [TypeError: cyclical structure in JSON object]
This error seems related to a cyclical reference within an object in my code. I'm unsure where this cycle is occurring or how to resolve it. The error message does not specify which part of my code contains the cyclical structure, making it difficult to pinpoint the exact issue.
I reviewed the objects used in the login function, looking for any references that might be circular, but nothing stood out.
I tried to stringyfy the object manually with JSON.stringify() to see if it would throw the same error. This confirmed a cyclical structure but didn’t help identify it.
My expectation was that the login would proceed smoothly and allow the user to log in without issues.
I would appreciate any guidance on how to debug cyclical references in objects in JavaScript, especially in the context of Expo/React Native.
const signInUserWithNumber = async () => {
        try {
            setIsLoading(true)
            setError('') // Clear any previous error messages

            const user = { number, password }

            // Make the POST request with user number and password
            const response = await axios.post('http://10.0.2.2:5000/login', user, {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
            })

            // If login is successful, store the token and navigate to the next screen
            const token = response.data.token
            await AsyncStorage.setItem('token', token)
            setToken(token)
            router.push('/link-up') // Navigate to link-up screen
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Login error:', error)
            setError('Login failed. Please check your number and password.')
        } finally {
            setIsLoading(false)
        }

//endpoint to login
app.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { number, password } = req.body

        // Check if the user exists already
        const user = await User.findOne({ number })
        if (!user) {
            return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Invalid number or password' })
        }

        // Compare provided password with hashed password in the database
        const isPasswordValid = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)
        if (!isPasswordValid) {
            return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Invalid password' })
        }

        // Generate JWT token upon successful login
        const secretKey = process.env.JWT_SECRET || 'defaultSecretKey'
        const token = jwt.sign({ userId: user._id }, secretKey, {
            expiresIn: '15m',
        })

        return res.status(200).json({ token })
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Login error:', error)
        res.status(500).json({ message: 'Login failed' })
    }
})


for cyclical references you can check TypeError: cyclic object value - JavaScript | MDN. My guess is that _id should be converted to string with something like _id.toString()
